# APIs sitting idle

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The app has 50+ total requests; 9 fetch requests and rest are assets (fonts, images etc). Following is the trend that app follows when it loads:

[image: app performance]

I am failing to understand why the app would sit idle for majority of the time. What might be the reasons for this kind of a behaviour?

Following is the app structure:

```
CH.event.on(
  'page.app.load',
  async (
    {
      fID,
      el,
      docId,
      isAdmin,
      isLoggedIn,
      userInfo,
      isLpp,
      forgetPasswordLink,
      playbookId,
    } = {}
  ) => {
    // first batch of requests which has 5 GET calls
    loadDatData({ fID, docId, playbookId: playbookId[4] });
    // second batch of requests which has 4 GET calls
    loadBackboneManagerData();
    await domLoaded;
    document.body.classList.add('dat_app');

    render(
      <App
        el={el}
        docId={docId}
        isAdmin={isAdmin}
        loggedin={isLoggedIn}
        userInfo={userInfo}
        forgetPasswordLink={forgetPasswordLink}
      />,
      document.querySelector(el)
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: That is a very broad question, without more info I doubt anyone can give you an answer that's anything more than a guess.

Comment: `50+ total requests` what does it mean? 50+ app endpoints? or 50+ request per day?

Comment: I have added sample code for the initial app render.

Comment: @num8er: For every page load there are 50 requests out of which 9 are GET api requests and rest are assets.

Comment: The problem is that app is taking more than a minute to load on every page refresh and out of that 1 minute majority of the time app is sitting idle.

Comment: is there any websocket stuff?

Comment: No websockets have been used.

Comment: Is there live edit/reload working?

Comment: I can edit html and css through browsers if that is what you meant to ask.

Comment: Local resources or CDN?

Comment: I meant to ask - does the site automatically update if you change something in your editor?

Comment: No it doesn't as of now.

Comment: Your page is publicly available?

Comment: Yes: https://www.clausehound.com/legal-contract/15656

Comment: It doesn't have the latest updates but the percentage of time the page sits in Idle mode is the same. Usually out of ~40 second first load time the page sits idle for ~25-30 seconds.

Comment: Fonts - as a test, remove all web fonts and see what happens. This usually comes down to two things - lots and lots and lots of garbage collection - which is not evident there - or the rendering process going off like crazy - which appears to be the issue. The CSS infrastructure is causing so much redraw that could be a cause too.

Comment: What's the issue with rendering according to you?

Comment: The page is using bundled css so there shouldnt be any with that I presume?

Comment: there is no idle, I don't know how You measure it :)

Comment: http://joxi.ru/l2Z33bHwqawpAJ see screenshot, it's loading fast and finishes. only think I saw is mouseflow that sends xhr request when I move cursor. but I don't think it's reason of idle.

Comment: can You give concrete url that is idle or pending?

Comment: Do you think the cdn or the project's hosting (WPEngine) somehow blacklists the ip in some way that is adding to the delay? We are a team of devs who work on this project and are on the same ip.

Comment: @AnAspiringCanadian in my experience I've such thing when site sticks on loading because of block on government level of some external service that we used. So, yes, that could be a problem